# c# type Bitmap is have in the system or we can create any kind of type

Tags: c#, types, bitmap

Bitmap In the code below we can create it or it is one type on c# system already

```
// Create a temporary bitmap...

Bitmap tmpBitmap = new Bitmap(1,1,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(tmpBitmap);
// measure the barcode size...

SizeF barCodeSize=objGraphics.MeasureString(barCodeString,c39Font);
```

Comment: I have no idea what the question is here... could you ask it a bit more clearly?

Comment: Bitmap is a class of System.Drawing Namespace its default type available in C#

Comment: do not forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmap is System Type...which you can find in `System.Drawing` namespace...

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx

Please use google and msdn. Or try to search in object browser under View menu of Visual studio